# Reactive Forms: dynamically add and delete to a type string array in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

How do I add a field to a reactive form that can dynamically add and delete to a type string array? The implementation I have right now is a FormArray, however it adds to the array as a object rather that just another string in the array. (see code below)

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    user: '',
    directory: '',
    filename: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
  });
}

createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    filename: ''
  });
}
```

Comment: You need to define the form as the class variable in order to access it everywhere!

Comment: @Exterminator It is declared in the code I just didn't include in the snippet. It works but I'm asking how to implement as adding to an array as a string rather than an object.

Comment: check this out [Reactive Forms in Angular: Dynamically Creating Form Fields With FormArray](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/)

Comment: @Exterminator that is the reference I am using right now.. Is there a way to just add input directly to an array instead of creating a formgroup for the FormArray?

Comment: yes, you can create template driven form instead of reactive form

Comment: oh i see! i am actually trying to create a dynamically created form. will this be possible with template driven forms?

Comment: yes, i guess. check the official documentation to know more about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating formGroup you can try this

```
constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder){
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    user: '',
    directory: '',
    filename: new FormArray([new FormControl('hai')])
  });

 }

 addFormInput(){
    const form=new FormControl('');
   (<FormArray>this.form.controls['filename']).push(form);
  }

removeFormInput(i){
  (<FormArray>this.form.get('filename')).removeAt(i);
 }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvuksw